# Solve linear equations on a Gram matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, lapack

Consider a case where, given an MxM matrix A and a vector b, I want to solve something of the form `inv(A @  A.T) @ b` (where I know A is invertible).
As far as I know, it is always faster to use `solve_*` rather than `inv`. There are also variants for more efficient solving for PSD matrices (which `A @ A.T` must be), using Cholesky factorization.

My question - since I'm constructing the matrix `A @ A.T` just to immediately throw it away - is there a more specialized procedure for solving linear equations with the gram matrix of A without having to construct it?

Comment: This sounds like it would be a good question to ask over in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the factorization of `A` and then use that to solve your system.

---

Assume we want to solve

```
A A^T x = b
```

for `x`.

Compute the factorization of `A=LU`.
Then solve `Ay=b` for `y`.
Then solve `A^T x = y` for `x`.

This way you dont have to compute the matrix `A^T A`.

---

Note that if one has a factorization of `A=LU` then one can solve `Ax=b` as well as `A^T x=b` efficiently for `x`.
This is because `A^T=U^T L^T` which is again a factorization of a lower times an upper triangular matrix.